# Solutions of a cubic diophantine equation in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, probability-theory

Suppose $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ is prime and $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$. Is there an estimate of the number of  solutions of $x^3+y^3=z^3$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, preferably using elementary number theory and algebra ? Can something be said about the "expected" ( in the sense of Probability Theory ) number of solutions ? I am particularly interested in large values of $p$ and elementary techniques.

Comment: Note thar $p \equiv 1 \mod 6$ or $p=6r+1$ so that $-1$ and $1$ both have three cube roots in the field, and one third of the non-zero elements are cubes.

Comment: The equation homogeneous: $(x,y,z)$ is a solution whenever $(ax,ay,az)$. This means that you can normalize $z=1$ or $z=0$. In the latter case you get $x=-\omega y$, where $\omega$ is one of the third roots of unity. IIRC an exact formula for the number of solutions to $x^3+y^3=1$ is known. I'm fairly sure that this is covered in Ireland & Rosen in the chapter about Jacobi sums. The expected value of solutions of that equation (with $z=1$) is close to $p$. This is because it is an elliptic curve, and we know that the number of points differs from $p+1$ by at most $2\sqrt p$. Gotta go...

Comment: Dear pritam, I have answered this question a week ago, but haven't gotten any feedback from you. If anything is unclear, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular problem is discussed in detail in Chapter 7 of *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves* by Silverman and Tate.

Let $p$ be a prime number. Let $M_p$ denote the number of (projective) solutions to $x^3+y^3\equiv z^3 (\text{mod } p)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Gauss proved that if $p\equiv 1 (\text{mod } 3)$, then there are integers $A$, and $B$ such that $4p=A^2+27B^2$. Up to sign, $A$ and $B$ are unique. Furthermore, if we fix the sign of $A$ to be positive, then in fact $M_p = p+1+A$.

So indeed, the theorem tells us exactly the number of solutions in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for this elliptic curve! I find this result striking and beautiful.

The proof given in the book is somewhat long, and uses clever manipulation of Gauss sums.

**Remark.** Last line of Jyrki's comment relates to quite an interesting result called [Hasse's bound.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves) Note that in the above case, this bound is verified: indeed, $4p=A^2+27B^2$ implies $A^2\le 4p$, giving us $A\le 2\sqrt{p}$. I highly recommend the above book by Silverman and Tate for accessible introduction to this topic and beyond.